# UISteppers - How to set a Stepper to restart from last value

Tags: ios, uistepper

In an application with more than one view controller, how can you setup a UIStepper so that it restarts from the last selected value when the button is pressed.

Currently if I move back and forth to my view with the Steppers, if I press the stepper button it resets the value in my label to its start default value.

I'd like it to increase/decrease from the last value selected by the user.

Thanks!

Comment: You should show the code you're using now. Also, how are you going back and forth between your view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

 int number = [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] integerForKey:@"value"];

 if(!number) { number = 1; };

 yourStep.value = number;

}

-(IBAction)changeValue:(UIStepper *)sender {

double value = [sender value];

int myValue = (int)value;

[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] setInteger:myValue forKey@"value"];

}
```

Comment: What's "yourStep.value"? not sure what I am supposed to put in there. thanks.

Comment: @user2659728 yourStep is name of your UIStepper and .value is property of UIStepper